# Highway overpass with modifiers

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to make an overpass type motorway with modifiers. Currently I am using one curve for the overpass and another version of that curve that has been flattened on Z axis. Then I use the Curve and Array modifiers to create this highway. I can use Shrinkwrap with the Vertex Group option to snap the bottom supports to the bottom of the motorway. Apart from that I don't know how to make it more believable. The different parts of the supports should change height and position according to the height of the curve, instead of just the top part stretching upwards like I have it. Are there any other techniques to create this kind of structure without modelling and positioning everything manually? Thanks!

[image: Overpass with supports, modeled with modifiers]

Answer (score 2):

OK I achieved a more or less satisfactory result by using multiple Shrinkwrap modifiers, and a hidden duplicate of the motorway geometry that the bottom vertices of the top parts of the supports are shrinkwrapping to. The middle parts of the supports are snapping to the top parts, etc... [image: motorways]